# What is polkitd doing when running ssh?

Tags: polkit

This will cause `polkitd` to burn CPU like crazy:

```
parallel ssh localhost echo ::: {1..1000}
```

From `top`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                   
 1908 root      20   0  294572   6872   3068 R  56.8  0.0 244:50.82 polkitd
```

Why? Is there a way to avoid having `polkitd` burning this much CPU?

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: Cant tell from what little you posted. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit or similar for your distro

Comment: @Panther What information do you need to determine the reason? And how do I acquire that information?

Comment: You posted nothing to suggest CPU use for example...

Comment: @Panther Output from `top` added.

Comment: You should probably file a bug report.  There are similar, older reports on launchpad. Perhaps one might have a work around